# OnlyINFO logs being dispalyed. DEBUG log not visible despite chaging log4.properties

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j

I wanted to understand the internal logging of the Kafka library. I figured out that we could use something like log4j for this. I'm currently only trying to log for the producer. The new output is as follows.

```
12:03:55.733 [com.kafkastuff.wordcount.producer.main()] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.6.0
12:03:55.733 [com.kafkastuff.wordcount.producer.main()] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
12:03:55.734 [com.kafkastuff.wordcount.producer.main()] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1604730835730
12:03:55.943 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: LDXMb3-6TLi5dEfsrvVJ-Q
```

I get this output irrespective of whether I execute my code as:

```
mvn exec:java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=~/Secure-Kafka-Storm/wordcount\ build\ fixed/src/main/java/com/kafkastuff/wordcount/log4j.properties -Dexec.mainClass=com.kafkastuff.wordcount.producer
```

or

```
mvn exec:java -Dlog4j.debug -Dexec.mainClass=com.kafkastuff.wordcount.producer
```

I set the rootlogger to True in my `log4j.properties` file as shown here and saved it class-path.(I also have a copy of it in my src/main/resources directory). PLS SKIP TO SEE THE LATEST EDIT.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the line below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=DEBUG, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also log allowed accesses
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=DEBUG, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```

(Edit)The new log4j.properties file is

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.logger.kafka=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=DEBUG

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=DEBUG
```

The following is pom.xml file. PLS SKIP TO SEE NEW EDIT

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.kafkastuff.wordcount</groupId>
<artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>wordcount</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

(Edit)The new pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.kafkastuff.wordcount</groupId>
<artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>wordcount</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My `producer.java` code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;


public class producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String topicName = "prototypeOneTopic";
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");    
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);   
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);   
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        
        Producer<String,String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props);
        
        for(int i = 0;i<100;i++) {
             producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, "I am borat" + Integer.toString(i), "I am borat" + Integer.toString(i)));
        }
        System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT");
        producer.close();
    }   
}
```

Can someone help me understand why I get this error and what I must do to debug and fix the same? I'm very new to Kafka, so I request y'all to help me out

Comment: 1) Remove log4j2 dependency. Kafka doesn't use it. Along with all the storm stuff and kafka_2.13 since you're not using any of that either... 2) You literally copied the broker log4j file, which isn't going to do any good for a client 3) Would also be worth using Junit5 and Java 11 for any brand new projects

Comment: Well we are using storm elsewhere.The issue seems like it's unable to identify the file for now. I think I'll start with this log4j file for now

Comment: Well, you're using log4j.properties, not log4j2.properties or log4j2.xml, so you should definitely remove those dependencies. And you can remove basically all the appenders except the stdout one and `log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO` because the producer isn't using any other package listed in your file

Comment: Should I replace it with some dependency for log4j2?

Comment: I think your problem now is that you're passing JVM flags for the log4j settings to `mvn`, not the exec plugin or your actual class